# Question was deleted during the reopening process

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I post the answer awarded with **9** upvotes [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804396/difference-between-202-and-202/39804453#39804453) with **4** upvotes (approximately 7 up-votes and 3 down-votes).

The question has been marked as duplicate by 2 users with a gold-badge in the main tag placed under the question. Yes, there was a relation to the question marked as duplicate of, however I found it a bit different, because the question does not fully provide the answer. Although the controversal voting ratio, it was proved as a question with an additional benefit to the SO community.

Thus I voted to reoprn the question and 1-2 more users voted the same like me.

Today the question was deleted so it caused me to lose over **100** reputation, that I see quite significant.

I am sure that OP had no reason to delete his own question when he marked the answer as accepted, moreover it was in the process of reopening. Moderators can delete any post instantly.

My question is, does have a moderator **a reason** to close this kind of question? What would happen with my lost reputation? There are lots of questions marked as duplicate and still available in the SO website with various range of upvotes. What's the difference?

Comment: It was deleted by 3 trusted users.

Comment: The duplicate provides a *much* better answer than yours.  It contains all of the same information, but it's of much higher quality, and also contains other tangential information on the subject.  I don't see *anything* in your answer that's not also covered in the duplicate.  What do you feel your answer was adding that the duplicate didn't cover? You've stated that you don't think the question is a duplicate, but provided no reasoning as for why.

Comment: No reason to delete it, it's a valid question with a valid asnwer. Voted to undelete it

Comment: I'll add that the reputation is not the main goal here, so don't focus on that. Content is the drive force. Duplicates are good, but when they are asked lots of times, there is no purpose in keeping them, it only dilutes the information more. This is the case at hand, here: of the 3 answers, 2 are very wrong (and even upvoted), while the 3rd, yours, is correct but largely covered with a lot more details in the linked question. All in all, it doesn't make it a question worthwile to  keep.

Comment: @Tunaki I agree with you. However I've to repeat that there are lots of questions marked as duplicate and still available in the SO. I have found only one question related to this one and IMO found it a bit different.

Comment: I agree with the question being closed as a duplicate, but not necessarily its deletion.  By deleting it, the asker has lost any references to an answer, even one that's been asked before.

Comment: Any chance of a screen shot for people who can't see the deleted question?

Comment: @Makoto The OP can still see the question in their history for 60 days.  If they wait that long for an answer it must not be that important.

Comment: @Makoto The OP can still access his own deleted question.

Comment: @JoeW: Here you go: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HyHiK.png

Comment: Seen this question a million times before. The OP did not earn those upvotes - IMNSHO. And frankly, *you* did not need to answer it, because It Is An Obvious Duplicate.

Answer (score 15):

I was one of the users who voted to delete the question. I did so because:

- The answer should have been found while researching.
- It is an n-th dupe that adds no value to the site.
- It had incorrect answers relating to operator precedence where the real issue was that the operator was not doing what the OP expected.

With those reasons I felt it was just better to delete it all. Yes, it stinks that you lose the rep, but we want high quality content and IMHO this was not it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the deletion is based on the personal feeling over the "vox pupuli"? I can point to many questions here that should be deleted according your criteria then.

Comment: So how does the OP find their answer now?  I'll admit they didn't do enough due diligence in searching the site, but the fact that we link to duplicate answers when we close them as duplicates gives them a better edge to find their solution.  I wholeheartedly agree with the closure, but I genuinely disagree with its deletion.

Comment: @Makoto Left you a comment on the question

Comment: All things considered, that's not satisfactory, given that it's slightly harder to find deleted content (even if it's your own), and anyone else that happens to Google something similar won't find it.

Comment: @Makoto The OP accepted an answer. It was deleted 2 days after that, long after they saw their answer.

Comment: @Tunaki:  You're assuming I'm talking about *just* the OP here.  I'm talking about other potential askers who would have a similar question.

Comment: @Makoto Google is a horrible reason in this case, as the relevant text for this question is not searchable in Google. No one would ever find this question via a Google search. They'd just get a bunch of random results which mention a lot of 0s and 2s. There are no searchable keywords here, hence it is not useful to keep around.

Comment: @Makoto Fair. But other askers have what to search for by [looking at the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for operators, which they should do. Or maybe even Documentation here :).

Comment: *"So the deletion is based on the personal feeling over the "vox pupuli""* all votes are based on personal feeling (aka opinions)... if they weren't we wouldn't need people voting at all and could handle it with algorithms.

Comment: "The answer should have been found while researching." is a terrible reason to delete a post.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker By itself, sure.  But in combination with the other reasons, it's something to take into consideration.